# Can a dropwizard application run on all operating systems on which java is supported.

Tags: dropwizard

Can a dropwizard application run on all operating systems on which java is supported. Is there a list of OS on which dropwizard is supported.

Comment: Dropwizard is an Open Source Software project. Your question will be better answered on their mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/dropwizard-user

Comment: Yes.. It will. Any operation system should be able to run Java and have ports opened.

Answer (score 0):

Drop-wizard is a java application, which runs on JVM(java virtual machine), which is supported by almost all the operating system.

So if your operating system supports JVM then it you are good to run your DW(dropwizrd) application on it.